# How to install Shopware demo data in existing installation?

Tags: shopware, demo, shopware6

Is there a way to install the Shopware demo data (not the random demo data) after an installation of the dev template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

**Solution 1:**

You are able to run the first run wizard in the dev template.

This can be done from `Settings > System > First run Wizard` here you will have to say "next" to the first step where it asks to install language package. At second step, you can install the demo data.

Just close the window or F5, after installing demo data plugin, you dont have to go through the whole run wizard again.

**Solution 2:**

```
composer require store.shopware.com/swagplatformdemodata
```

Comment: cant we also run it on the console like this: `bin/console framework:demodata` ?

Comment: running the command is not the same as installing the demo data plugin!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer as of version 6.2.0-RC version we can use the `bin/console store:download` (added in this [commit](https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/a1b7eca707b72b51265c264e9c060a2ab4d07213)) command to install this demo data plugin (no credentials needed).

Example:

```sh
APP_ENV=prod php bin/console store:download -p SwagPlatformDemoData
```

---

As mentioned the comments, installing `bin/console framework:demodata` installs random demo data. It may not be helpful if you want to run tests on a specific set of data.

The proposed Solution 2 is also no go:

```
Could not find a matching version of package store.shopware.com/swagplatformdemodata
```

It is possible that it is now located at `packages.shopware.com`.
For that you will have to add a repository to your root composer:

```
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packages.shopware.com"
    }
  ]
```

But you will need login credentials in the `/.composer/auth.json` for that one to work:

```
 {
    bearer: {
       "packages.shopware.com: "[TOKEN]"
    }
 }
```

Token should be grabbed from https://account.shopware.com (if you able to get it ^_^)